# Javascript adding an element into another element without id

Tags: javascript, dom

Goal - I want to add "Start was Clicked!" inside the "**main**" element of my Html file.

This is the body of my Html File.

```
   <body>
     <h1></h1>

     <p>First paragraph.</p>

     <p class="intro">Second <span>paragraph</span>.</p>

     <button id="start">Start</button>

     <main></main>
</body>
```

This is my js code.

```
    let button = document.querySelector('#start')
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let elem = document.createElement('span');
    elem.innerText = "Start was clicked!";
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
}); // This just appends to bottom of the page, how would I add it to the main element without an id.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `document.querySelector("main")` to select the `<main>` element.

```js
let button = document.querySelector('#start')
let main = document.querySelector('main')
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let elem = document.createElement('span');
  elem.innerText = "Start was clicked!";
  main.appendChild(elem);
});
```

```html
<h1></h1>

<p>First paragraph.</p>

<p class="intro">Second <span>paragraph</span>.</p>

<button id="start">Start</button>

<main></main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use tagname instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1></h1>

<p>First paragraph.</p>

<p class="intro">Second <span>paragraph</span>.</p>

<button id="start">Start</button>

<main></main>

<script>
    let btn = document.getElementById("start")
    let main = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0]
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        let elem = document.createElement('span');
        elem.innerText = "Start was clicked!";
        main.appendChild(elem)
    });
    // This just appends to bottom of the page, how would I add it to the main element without an id.
</script>


</body>
</html>
```